# Show on Click - CSS, HTML5

Tags: css, html

I've got a quick question:

I've got a quick table, in which there's something clickeable.

```
<table class ="tablez">
    <tr>
        <th>Table Title </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a class="clickable">Click Me!</a>
            <div id="showedClickable">
                <p>This is showed when Click Me! is clicked.</p> 
            </div><!--EO showedClickable -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I want to accomplish is:

```
#showedClickable {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
}
```

This is the part I don't know how to 'phrase'...How do I do so that

```
a.clickable:focus + #showedClickable {
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that an `a` element without a `href` does not receive focus by default. This is why your code is not working. You should give it a [`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-tabindex) to make it focusable.

```
<a tabindex="0" class="clickable">Click Me!</a>
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y2C98/)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show the `div` on click of `a` like your title indicates, you can do it by modifying the code as below:

**HTML:**

```
<a href='#showedClickable' class="clickable">Click Me!</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
#showedClickable:target {
    display:block;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/D7C9d/)

**EDIT:**

`:target` is a pseudo-class which matches an element whose `id` is the same as that of the fragment identifier of the URI.

URIs with fragment identifiers link to a certain element within the document, known as the target element. In this case, the target (`href` of anchor) is an element with `id` as `showedClickable`. Hence when the anchor is clicked, the content gets displayed.

You can find more details about `:target` pseudo-class [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3atarget)

*Note:* As bažmegakapa has pointed out in the comments, this method **will not work** in **IE 8 and lower**.

Comment: +1 this is a nice idea if you do not care about old IE (8 or lower).

Comment: @bažmegakapa: Thanks mate. Went down this route as OP has tagged HTML5. Not sure if there is a need to support lower IE versions though.

Comment: upvoted thanks for the info about :target really helpful. but our old IEs :(

Comment: @user1876553: When should it be hidden? Page load (or) button click? In the current fiddle, it his hidden by default and displayed only when it is the target (meaning, only when its corresponding link is clicked).

Comment: So if I had multiple clickMe's when I click the second one the first should Disappear?

Comment: @user1876553: Yes. In the example fiddle itself, we have two such items and when one is shown the other disappears :)